# How can I write table_print output within my Ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formatting

So, I've got a script, say, program.rb, and in it I want to output the [table_print](http://tableprintgem.com/) version of an array of lists

```
['value1','value2','value3']
['value4','value4','value6']
```

so that it looks like this in the .txt file I output

```
  col1              | col2              | col3
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  value1            | value2            | value3
  .
  .
  .
```

I already have table_print installed, but this is all I have so far as a working model:

```
require 'table_print'

TABLEPRINT STUFF?

open('table_print_output.txt','a'){|g|
    g.puts TABLEPRINT?
}
```

I guess I'm just not getting how to do the Ruby equivalent of MySQL's create table

```
CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)
```

and insert into

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

And I don't want a temporary/latent database just sitting around for no reason. It's like I need a database as a variable or something; that is, I create it, I populate it, I print it, I destroy it.

Comment: Do try and allow a little more room for names and email addresses. Unless you have a very compelling reason to restrict something, use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default.

Comment: Yes, I know, I use VARCHAR(255), I just copied that as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table_print` can't print nested arrays like this:

```
arrays = [
  ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
  ['value4', 'value5', 'value6']
]
```

because it flattens the input. You have to convert the inner arrays to another object.

[`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html) would work:

```
hashes = array.map { |values| %w(col1 col2 col3).zip(values).to_h }
#=> [
#     {"col1"=>"value1", "col2"=>"value2", "col3"=>"value3"},
#     {"col1"=>"value4", "col2"=>"value5", "col3"=>"value6"}
#   ]

tp hashes
# COL1   | COL2   | COL3
# -------|--------|-------
# value1 | value2 | value3
# value4 | value5 | value6
```

[`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Struct.html) would work as well:

```
Row = Struct.new(:col1, :col2, :col3)
rows = arrays.map { |values| Row.new(*values) }
#=> [
#     #<struct Row col1="value1", col2="value2", col3="value3">,
#     #<struct Row col1="value4", col2="value5", col3="value6">
#   ]

tp rows
# COL1   | COL2   | COL3
# -------|--------|-------
# value1 | value2 | value3
# value4 | value5 | value6
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `String#ljust`:

```
rows = [
  ['value1','value2','value3'],
  ['value4','value4','value6']
]

rows.each do |row|
  puts "#{row[0].ljust(30)}|#{row[1].ljust(30)}|#{row[2].ljust(30)}"
end
```